# Where is energy lost in the system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Here's the situation

There is a disc of mass $M$, radius $R$. The axis is passing through the Centre of the disc, perpendicular to the plane.  A man has mass M and is initially on the axis. The system is given angular velocity w. Assume all surfaces to be smooth

The man will slide to the edge of the disc, and as angular momentum is conserved, we can find out the new angular velocity.

However, if I find the energy, I find a loss in kinetic energy, despite there being no other force

Where is the energy lost?

Comment: I'm going to suppose the energy is lost in a mistake in your analysis. Which you did not show.

Comment: If the man is in the center of the disk, he will remain in the center no matter what the spin is....

Comment: If the surface is frictionless, then the man should be able to slide out and off the disc with some small initial velocity, and the disc would be unaffected.  If you want the man to remain on the disc (as it seems you are doing) then there must be some force that does work on him to bring him to $v_f = \omega_f R$, e.g., the force of static friction on his shoes as he walks from center to edge.

Answer (score 1):

The system is given angular momentum, energy is given to the system. Assuming this is the starting point.  In the absence of friction(smooth surface), the mass will continue to go in a straight line to its initial tangential velocity. And the disk maintains its initial rotational ke. Energy is conserved.

What about your initial state did you assume? I would assume you inadvertently considered friction, aka the final result is the mass rotating in a circular fashion at a larger radius, in doing so you need to consider the friction force more carefully as the energy is transfered into the disk as vibrational ke

Comment: Wont there be decrease in KE of the system when the man is at the edge as angular speed decreases?

I havent considered friction in the system

Comment: Setting the reference to be the center of the disk,  the rotating disk carries some rotational ke, and the mass has some linear kinetic energy, there are no forces acting on the mass, hence its kinetic energy is unchanged. You are confusing the wrong  formula that $E_{total}$ = kinetic energy + rotational ke. Let's completely forget the disk, since the disk has absolutely nothing to do with the problem since we aren't  considering friction. We give the mass some KE,  this object either can be thought of having

Comment: A: a kinetic  energy equal to $\frac{1}{2} m |\vec{v}|^2$ which remains unchanged.

Comment: Or B: this can be thought of having some rotational kinetic  energy plus kinetic  energy parrallel to the r vector $1/2 I \omega^2 + 1/2 m (r')^2$ as the rotational kinetic  energy decreases as it gets further out, the component of the linear ke increases

Comment: The OP states "The man will slide to the edge of the disc, and as angular momentum is conserved, we can find out the new angular velocity." But in your formulation the angular velocity doesn't change, so you aren't addressing the OP.

Comment: This seems to be a wording problem instead of a physics problem. OP's question says the surface is smooth, given an object is given some velocity along with the disk, there are now no forces acting on either the disk or the mass. My formation the angular momentum of the disk is unchanged since no forces act on it. The angular momentum of the mass is unchanged since no forces are acting on it since there is no friction, due to this linear trajectory the mass will "move to the edge of the disk" , there is obviously a change in angular velocity for an object moving in a straight line at a

Comment: Constant speed. Your answer seems to imply that the mass is on a circular trajectory at a larger radius, this is not what would.actually happen in OP's scenario. I agree with your analysis if this WERE the case, but it is not.

Comment: @jensenpaull What's not the case? It's clear that the OP was about how the angular velocity *changes* and how KE isn't conserved when that happens. That's inconsistent with the assumption of no friction. Your approach takes the faulty assumption seriously, mine rejects it.

Comment: OP's calculation of the situation described was wrong. Your correct, this situation is inconsistent with the assumption of no friction, which OP said was a condition in the question. That is the answer to OP's question.  He is miscalculating what happens, and as a result gets the false answer that energy is lost, since he is actually taking a situation in which friction does exist and isn't accounting for the energy transfered due to friction. My answer is stating what ACTUALLY happens  in his described scenario. His calculations assume false assumptions  which is the answer to his question

Comment: @jensenpaull Physics is about what happens in reality, which is what my answer (including friction) addresses. And yours isn't "stating what ACTUALLY happens in his described scenario", because in his described scenario, angular velocity changes and energy is lost.

Comment: "all surfaces to be smooth" - no friction. His account  of the end result of his situation is wrong. I don't see why you're trying to include friction when his question  clearly says it doesnt.

Comment: No friction- no forces- no change in kinetic energy for either object. "There is a disc of mass M, radius R. The axis is passing through the Centre of the disc, perpendicular to the plane. A man has mass M and is initially on the axis. The system is given angular velocity w. Assume all surfaces to be smooth"  anything after this sentence is irrelevant. I described the end result of the scenario as laid out by OP. op's entire question was asking why his calculations said a loss of energy  and the simple answer is because he hasn't reasoned what actually happens correctly.

Comment: If OP had referenced friction, then fair enough, but he didn't, which is why he didn't take into account the energy transfered as vibrational ke in the disk, whilst assuming the end result was a situation with friction.Which is the answer to his question

Answer (score 0):

Classic playground experiment. It's easier to understand in the other direction. Spin up the merry-go-round while standing on its edge. Then pull yourself to the center. This adds energy to the rotation. Note that I said "pull": you must do work to add the energy.

In the other direction, as you move outward you must use your muscles as brakes, dissipating energy.

I did this experiment many times in the days when I had young children ツ

Comment: This isn't the question OP asks, friction isn't applicable here and no energy is lost

Comment: @jensenpaull But energy must be lost for the stated condition that the man slides to the edge of the disk and, by implication, no further.

Comment: @JohnDoty Energy isn't lost, it's converted to potential energy w.r.t to the centrifugal force field.

Comment: Sliding to the edge of the disk is a consequence of the mass moving in a straight line due to its initial ke, there is no friction as said by OP

Comment: @jensenpaull Then the implied condition that it stops at the edge is wrong. There is no change in either angular velocity of the disk or the linear velocity of the mass, so the problem is trivial. But that's not the question.

Comment: Slides to the edge to me doesn't imply it stops, with no friction this is impossible unless there is a wall, in which case your analysis is still wrong,  since your answer assumes the final result is a mass moving in a  circle at a larger radius which would not be the case here with no friction

Answer (score 0):

In the frame rotating with the disk there is a centrifugal force potential energy:

$$ \phi_c(r) = -\frac 1 2 \omega^2r^2 $$

This leads to the centrifugal force:

$$ \vec F_c = -\vec\nabla \phi_c(r) = \omega^2 \vec r $$

There is also a Coriolis force vector potential:

$$ \vec A(r) = 2\omega  \hat{\theta} $$

with a curl:

$$ \vec \nabla \times \vec A = \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(rA) = 2\omega \hat z = 2\vec\omega$$

leading to a Coriolis force:

$$ F_c = \vec v \times 2\vec\omega = -2\vec\omega \times \vec v$$

As far as conversation is concerned, only the centrifugal force is conservative (a gradient), so changing $r$ requires doing work against/with that force.

Comment: What happens to the kinetic energy of the mass when it stops at the edge instead of flying away? That seems to be the lost energy of the OP. In real life, you need some friction to keep the mass confined to the disk.

Comment: @JohnDoty was it a disk? If it doesn't bounce and just stops, then at kinetic energy is converted to vibrationally modes of the disk (and maybe deformation). Those modes emit sound energy and the rest is convert internal degrees of freedom: faster molecules = heat. The surface is frictionless, so we can ignore that, but transverse modes can also transfer energy to other objects.

Comment: The OP says "There is a disc ...".  What brings it to a halt at the edge is unspecified, but an end state with the mass at the edge, rotating with the disk, is implied. In real life, friction would produce this end state. I don't think the OP visualizes other organized motion like vibration.

Comment: Stopping w/o deformation / vibration violates special relativity.

Comment: Silly. Relativistic effects are negligible with such an apparatus made of actual materials. But, of course, some deformation will be associated with friction. But deformation by itself cannot produce the implied end state.

Comment: @John Doty See: Born Rigidity.

Comment: See if you can measure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either neglect totally disc and concentrate for man only or solve for disc with man. When the man is at distance $r_1$ from centre of disc, his inertia is $I_1$ and angular speed $\omega_1$. Remember here we neglect gravity producing torque as man moves radially which reduces angular speed of disc.

As there is no friction so one may say that the man is not rotating, but we are talking about force from disc and that depends upon rotation. So similarly at distance $r_2$, moment of inertia and angular speed are $I_2$ and $\omega_2$.

Now if there is no external torque then from conservation of angular momentum, $$\omega_2=\frac{I_1}{I_2}\omega_1$$

But rotational kinetic energy is not zero as asked in question as missing. First thing conservation of kinetic energy applied where time factor is negligble. Here time is taken by man to move from one point to another, also in presence of two forces, centrifugal and coriolis. We can neglect coriolis by assuming distance is short, otherwise not.

So, difference in rotational kinetic energy is transferred to linear motion of the man moving from rest at $r_1$ to speed $v$ at $r_2$, thus$$I_1\omega^2_1-I_2\omega^2_2=Mv^2$$

Answer (score 0):

"There is a disc of mass M"
The axis is passing through the Centre of the disc, perpendicular to the plane. A man has mass M and is initially on the axis. The system is given angular velocity w. Assume all surfaces to be smooth"

**What actually happens:**

Since there is no friction there are no external forces acting on the man or the disk.

Angular velocity does not mean an object is rotating around circularly, this is simply a measure if the rate at which angle changes about some reference location.

Assuming the disk maintains its shape, it will rotate around its axis. The man however, under the influence of no forces,  will continue to move in a straight line with the same velocity ( angular velocity will still change but that has no impact on the energy)

**Your confusion:**

I assume in your analysis of this scenario you assumed that the man is rotating in a circular fashion at some initial radius, and then again is rotating at some larger radius in a circular fashion.

This is not what would happen in your described scenario, in considering this scenario you have not considered the work done/against the force of friction, hence your discrepancy in energy conservation.

I assume you'd have done something like this:

$$L= L_{man} + L_{disk}$$

$$L=rmv + k \omega$$

$(v= \omega r)$ the same $\omega$ as the disk

$$L= r^2m\omega + k \omega$$

$$\frac{L}{r^2m+ k} = \omega$$

$$KE_{man} = \frac{1}{2}m  (\frac{Lr}{r^2m+ k})^2$$

$$KE_{disk} = \frac{1}{2}I (\frac{L}{r^2m+ k})^2$$

Here I've moddeled a scenario that the man is always moving in a circle, which is false with your scenario. I have moddeled with friction such that there is no "slipping" perpendicular to the radial direction aka the angular frequency of the man and disk are the same, as the radius increases the kinetic energy of the man and the disk decreases. This isn't a mistake, it's just that we are not considering the force of friction. See the  above answers about the coriolis force, this is the "force" that friction negates, and is where the missing energy is.

Comment: Go to a playground and do the experiment. What actually happens is that energy is lost to friction. You're describing what happens on paper when you use a faulty assumption (no friction).

Comment: I am answering OP's question as described. OP said no friction, and hence I answer as such. Not sure what you're trying to get at. I think I've done a good Job at explaining the scenario and where he went wrong with his assumptions about the net result. ---------"A man is travelling at 5 m/s   assuming no friction, what is the speed of the man after 1 second". " 5 m/s"  "well actually friction does exist" , that's not the question

Comment: The stated question is "Where is energy lost in the system?". Since the energy is lost to friction, an analysis of what happens if you assume no friction is not responsive to the question.